# [Problem]Made a bot using Discordia, but it is not reacting in discord-channeles while it reacts ain DMs

Tags: lua, discord

Read the discordia doc and made a bot.

Here is the bot's code:

````
local discordia = require('discordia')
local client = discordia.Client()

client:on('ready', function()
    print('Logged in as ' .. client.user.username)
end)

local function code(str)
    return string.format('```\n%s```', str)
end

local function log(str)
    local file = io.open("luabot.log", "a") -- append mode
    if file then
        file:write("[LOG] " .. str .. "\n")
        file:close()
    end
end

local function LoadAsciiArtFromFile()
    local file = io.open("asciiart.txt", "r")
    if file then
        local asciiArt = file:read("*a")
        file:close()
        return asciiArt
    end
end

local sandbox = setmetatable({
    os = {},
    io = {},
    debug = {},
    package = {}
}, {
    __index = _G
})

local function exec(arg, msg)

    if not arg then
        return
    end
    ---if msg.author ~= msg.client.owner then return end

    arg = arg:gsub('```\n?', '') -- strip markdown codeblocks

    local lines = {} -- this is where our printed lines will collect

    sandbox.message = msg

    sandbox.print = function(...) -- intercept printed lines with this
        local ret = {}
        for i = 1, select('#', ...) do
            local arg = tostring(select(i, ...))
            table.insert(ret, arg)
        end
        local line = table.concat(ret, '\t')
        log(line) -- logging
        table.insert(lines, table.concat(ret, '\t'))
    end

    local fn, syntaxError = load(arg, 'DiscordBot', 't', sandbox)
    if not fn then
        return msg:reply(code(syntaxError))
    end

    local success, runtimeError = pcall(fn) -- run the code
    if not success then
        return msg:reply(code(runtimeError))
    end -- handle runtime errors

    lines = table.concat(lines, '\n')

    if #lines > 1990 then -- truncate long messages
        lines = lines:sub(1, 1990)
    end

    return msg:reply(code(lines))

end

client:on('messageCreate', function(message)
    if message.content == '!ping' then
        message.channel:send('Pong!')
    end
    if message.content == '!love' then
        local asciiArt = LoadAsciiArtFromFile()
        message.channel:send(asciiArt)
    end
    -- Only process messages starting with "!lua"
    if message.content:sub(1, 4) ~= '!lua' then
        return
    end

    -- Extract the code from the message
    local code = message.content:sub(5)

    -- Execute the code
    exec(code, message)
end)

client:run('Bot MyBotToken')
````

[Bot reacting at channels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78RX4.png)
[Bot reacting at DMs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swAhm.png)

I added a role(permissions) in discord but I dont know how to configure it.

**I have solved the problem while writing this sorry.**
At [discord developer's portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), I turned on the permission in the **Privileged Gateway Intents** section(I don't know what it means)

```
Privileged Gateway Intents

Some Gateway Intents require approval if your bot is verified. If your bot is not verified, you can toggle those intents below to access them.
Presence Intent

Required for your bot to receive Presence Update events.

NOTE: Once your bot reaches 100 or more servers, this will require verification and approval. Read more here
Server Members Intent

Required for your bot to receive events listed under GUILD_MEMBERS.

NOTE: Once your bot reaches 100 or more servers, this will require verification and approval. Read more here
Message Content Intent

Required for your bot to receive message content in most messages.

NOTE: Once your bot reaches 100 or more servers, this will require verification and approval. Read more here
```